# Getting rid of the blue dot at the bottom left of the graph, coordinate 0,0?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do i get rid of the blue dot that is at the 0,0 coordinate of my graph?

Note: This is a clustered graph with a separated line graph above the individual bars

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotsset{
        my axis style/.style={
            width=\linewidth,
            ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
            ybar=5pt,
            bar width=0.30cm,
            enlarge y limits=0.0,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,      
            xticklabels from table={\data}{material},
            xtick={data},
            table/x expr={\coordindex},
            xtick align=inside,
            minor y tick num=1,
            scaled y ticks=false, 
            yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        },
           Name/.style={
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={
            coordinate,
            name=#1\coordindex,
            mark=*, % add red circle at node
            mark options={mark size=2pt, fill=red}, % set size and fill color of mark
        },
    },
    }
    
    \pgfplotstableread{
    material d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6
    CPU 0.25 0.21 0.23  0.33 0.25 0.28 75 63 71 85 70 80
    GPU 0.18 0.16 0.17 0.22 0.18 0.20 77 65 72 84 69 79
    FPGA 0.19 0.15 0.18 0.25 0.16 0.19 69 59 68 80 68 74
    }{\data}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[        my axis style,           legend image code/.code={\draw[#1, draw=none, fill=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.3cm,0.25cm);
                    },     ymin=0, ymax=0.5,      axis x line*=bottom,        axis y line*=left,        ylabel=Execution time (ms),        
    cycle list={
      {draw=black, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=black, fill=blue!20, postaction={pattern=north east lines}},
      {draw=black, pattern=grid, pattern color=black, fill=blue!20,postaction={pattern=grid}},
      {draw=black, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=black, fill=blue!20,postaction={pattern=horizontal lines}},
      {draw=black, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=black, fill=red!20,postaction={pattern=north east lines}},
      {draw=black, pattern=grid, pattern color=black, fill=red!20,postaction={pattern=grid}},
      {draw=black, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=black, fill=red!20,postaction={pattern=horizontal lines}},
    },
        scaled y ticks=false, 
        ]
            \addplot table [y=d1] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d2] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d3] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d4] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d5] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d6] {\data};
            \legend{{Baseline}, {Datatype}, {Downsampling}}
        \end{axis}
    
        \begin{axis}[        my axis style,  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.08)},
          anchor=north,legend columns=-1},      ymin=0,    ymax=100,        axis y line*=right,        ylabel=Accuracy (\%),        xticklabels=\empty,        only marks,     scaled y ticks=false, 
       ]
            \addplot [Name=a] table [y=T1] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=b] table [y=T2] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=c] table [y=T3] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=d] table [y=T4] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=e] table [y=T5] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=f] table [y=T6] {\data};
            \legend{{\color{blue!50}\rule{5mm}{2mm} \textcolor{black}{MobileNetV2}}, {\color{red!50}\rule{5mm}{2mm} \textcolor{black}{Resnet18}}}
        \end{axis}
    
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5} {
        \fill [red!90] (d\i) circle (2pt);
        \fill [blue!90] (a\i) circle (2pt);
        \draw [very thick,red!90] (d\i) -- (e\i) -- (f\i);
        \draw [very thick,blue!90] (a\i) -- (b\i) -- (c\i);
        \fill [red!90] (e\i) circle (2pt);
        \fill [red!90] (f\i) circle (2pt);
        \fill [blue!90] (b\i) circle (2pt);
        \fill [blue!90] (c\i) circle (2pt);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE does not compile. You need to add some more packages and libraries. Anyways: Your table has only 3 rows, but you say `\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5}` which means that you iterate over coordinates that don't exist (such as `d3`, but since you have three table rows, there are only `d0`, `d1` and `d2`). If Ti*k*Z is told to draw something at an undefined coordinate, it will output an error and draw at `(0,0)` instead. Replace `\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5}` by  `\foreach \i in {0,1,2}` and everything should work out fine.

Comment: Ah, you're right, i may have tried it before and it ending up doing something else.

ill edit the above code so it works.

Comment: You may post the fix and ill approve it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you iterate over too many numbers in the `\foreach` loop at the end of your code.

The table you define has only three rows. In the second `axis` environment, you define coordinates based on the six columns `T1` to `T6` and the three rows of this table, which are named `a0`, `a1`, `a2`, `b0`, `b1`, `b2` ... and so on up to `f2`. Now, in the `\foreach` loop at the end of your code, you iterate over `0,1,2,3,4,5`, but the coodinate `d3` (and all the following coordinates) has never been defined before. If Ti*k*Z is told to draw something at an undefined coordinate, it throws an error and draws at coordinate `(0,0)` instead. This is why you get these dots at the origin.

The solution is quite simple: Replace `\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5}` by `\foreach \i in {0,1,2}` and everything should be fine:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % pgfplotstable loads pgfplots, pgfplots loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotsset{
        my axis style/.style={
            width=\linewidth,
            ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
            ybar=5pt,
            bar width=0.30cm,
            enlarge y limits=0.0,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,      
            xticklabels from table={\data}{material},
            xtick={data},
            table/x expr={\coordindex},
            xtick align=inside,
            minor y tick num=1,
            scaled y ticks=false, 
            yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        },
        Name/.style={
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style={
                coordinate,
                name=#1\coordindex,
                mark=*, % add red circle at node
                mark options={mark size=2pt, fill=red}, % set size and fill color of mark
            },
        },
    }
    
    \pgfplotstableread{
    material d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6
    CPU 0.25 0.21 0.23  0.33 0.25 0.28 75 63 71 85 70 80
    GPU 0.18 0.16 0.17 0.22 0.18 0.20 77 65 72 84 69 79
    FPGA 0.19 0.15 0.18 0.25 0.16 0.19 69 59 68 80 68 74
    }{\data}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            my axis style,
            legend image code/.code={
                \draw[#1, draw=none, fill=none] 
                    (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.3cm,0.25cm);
            },
            ymin=0,
            ymax=0.5,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line*=left,
            ylabel=Execution time (ms),        
            cycle list={
                {draw=black, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=black, fill=blue!20, postaction={pattern=north east lines}},
                {draw=black, pattern=grid, pattern color=black, fill=blue!20,postaction={pattern=grid}},
                {draw=black, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=black, fill=blue!20,postaction={pattern=horizontal lines}},
                {draw=black, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=black, fill=red!20,postaction={pattern=north east lines}},
                {draw=black, pattern=grid, pattern color=black, fill=red!20,postaction={pattern=grid}},
                {draw=black, pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=black, fill=red!20,postaction={pattern=horizontal lines}},
            },
            scaled y ticks=false, 
        ]
            \addplot table [y=d1] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d2] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d3] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d4] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d5] {\data};
            \addplot table [y=d6] {\data};
            \legend{{Baseline}, {Datatype}, {Downsampling}}
        \end{axis}
    
        \begin{axis}[
            my axis style,
            legend style={
                at={(0.5,-0.08)},
                anchor=north,
                legend columns=-1
            },
            ymin=0,
            ymax=100,
            axis y line*=right,
            ylabel=Accuracy (\%),
            xticklabels=\empty,
            only marks,
            scaled y ticks=false, 
       ]
            \addplot [Name=a] table [y=T1] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=b] table [y=T2] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=c] table [y=T3] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=d] table [y=T4] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=e] table [y=T5] {\data};
            \addplot [Name=f] table [y=T6] {\data};
            \legend{
                {\color{blue!50}\rule{5mm}{2mm} \textcolor{black}{MobileNetV2}}, 
                {\color{red!50}\rule{5mm}{2mm} \textcolor{black}{Resnet18}}
            }
        \end{axis}
    
        \foreach \i in {0,1,2} {
            \fill [blue!90] (a\i) circle (2pt);
            \fill [blue!90] (b\i) circle (2pt);
            \fill [blue!90] (c\i) circle (2pt);
            \draw [very thick,blue!90] (a\i) -- (b\i) -- (c\i);
            \fill [red!90] (d\i) circle (2pt);
            \fill [red!90] (e\i) circle (2pt);
            \fill [red!90] (f\i) circle (2pt);
            \draw [very thick,red!90] (d\i) -- (e\i) -- (f\i);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]